# ntfs or partion or something; can't mount seagte expansion drive on upgrade to Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have two HP laptops, one rather old and one newer but still old. Before I upgraded them to 22.04, I backed up my files onto a 2TB Seagate hard drive. I did this from the existing laptops which mounted and ran the drive perfectly. Now, neither will mount the drive. it has something to do with formatting or the drive's name or ntfs or something. I've tried all sorts of command line help while wading through the online forums for Ubuntu, but everything I find is either incomplete in its instruction or doesn't work. An answer will, for example, say something like, "Rename the mount location".  I don't know how to do that. Sometimes it says to run the drive in Windows to reformat, but I don't have Windows. It's particularly galling because this drive has only ever been used with an Ubuntu OS, and it always just mounted right up. I'd love to sort this out because I need some of those files on the drive and it's almost as if I had let them be overwritten after all. I would love some clear, somewhat detailed explanation of what needs to be done and why along with the code to do it. Is there a site like that for someone who has only a rudimentary understanding of how this works and knows only a smattering of commanded code.

Comment: You've not been specific enough with details for me to fully understand your issue, you mention upgrade to 22.04; was that a 21.10 upgrade to 22.04??  as *release-upgrades* from 20.04 were not supported & could result in breakage (https://ubuntustudio.org/2022/04/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-released/)  You've not said how you attempted to mount the external NTFS drive?  where showing the command & output/errors would allow us to understand; or if GUI what exactly you did & any messages shown (or in logs? did you look? commands are easier to copy/paste for us to see).

Comment: I did not. I unmounted the drive and waited until I was told it was safe to remove the drive. and judging from the number of people looking for help for this same problem it appears to be fairly common.

Comment: well thank you for that link, I was missing most of the studio programs and did not know why. still can't load my drive. but l'ii figure it out somehow